# Pass alias from chained command to unalias

Tags: bash

I have a list of `alias` definitions in a file I want to `unalias` in a batch.

The file looks like this:

```
please=sudo
po='git push origin'
```

I have come this far but I'm not sure how to pass the alias names to the `unalias` com

```
cat old.txt | cut -d = -f 1
```

Comment: As an aside, it's more efficient to run `foo <input` than `cat input | foo`; the former gives `foo` a handle directly on the file, the second forces it to read from a FIFO connected to a *different* program (`/usr/bin/cat`) that has a handle on the real/underlying file. That might be a fairly small change for `cut`, but if you're trying to use `tail` to get the last few lines of a 4GB file, or `wc -c` to find its size, the difference is enormous (as one can get stat metadata from a real file handle, or seek straight to the end of it, but can't see through a FIFO to the file on the other side).

Comment: (Similarly, GNU `sort` can parallelize and have different subprocesses read different chunks of a large input file and do a merge-sort to combine their results... but a FIFO can only be read once, front-to-back, so `cat foo | sort` can't be optimized in ways that `sort foo` or  `sort <foo` is eligible for).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If you post it as an answer I'll accept that.

Comment: *shrug*. More a general-purpose aside; if I'm going to add an answer, I'd probably avoid relying on string-splitting in the first place. But sure, I'll add an answer that provides a non-string-splitting-based approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow the input file to contain comments, you might do something like:

```
while IFS== read -r name val; do
  [[ $val ]] || continue # skip any line that didn't have a "="
  [[ $name =~ [#] ]] && continue # skip any line that had a # anywhere before the "="
  unalias "$name"
done <old.txt
```

This avoids relying on any tools external to the shell itself -- all processing is done with bash-native logic. (Sometimes this is the right thing, sometimes it's not -- bash's string processing tends to be slower than general-purpose tools, but those tools typically also have significant startup-time costs, making them undesirable to run in a loop).

- The `while read` idiom is documented in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Setting `IFS==` means that we split into fields when an `=` is seen; providing `name` and `val` means that the first field goes into `name`, and all subsequent fields go into `val`.
- `[[ $var =~ $regex ]]` does POSIX ERE-style regex matching.
- `... <in.txt` is both more efficient than `cat in.txt | ...`, and avoids triggering the issues described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) (which can happen when piping data into a loop).

Comment: Why not just `awk -F= 'NF>1 && $1 !~ /#/ { print $1 } old.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
unalias $(cat old.txt | cut -d = -f 1)
```

Comment: The `cat` is still [useless](/q/11710552); `cut` knows how to read a file, too (as do `grep`, `wc`, `nl`, `sed`, `awk` etc and generally all text manipulation utilities except, inexplicably, `tr`).

Comment: Shorter: `unalias $( cut -d = -f 1 old.txt )`